# Get min value except 0 in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1, min

I'm trying to get the min value ignoring 0 inside a laravel model using MySQL `nullif`.

I'm using this code with no luck:

```
static function etomin($month, $year)
{

    return day::where(\DB::raw('month(fecha)'), $month)
        ->where(\DB::raw('year(fecha)'), $year)->get()
        ->min(NULLIF('evotranspiration', 0))
}
```

Comment: title fixed, cod block fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. NOT TESTED.

```
static function etomin($month, $year){
    return day::where(\DB::raw('month(fecha)'), $month)
        ->where(\DB::raw('year(fecha)'), $year)
        ->where('evotranspiration','!=',0)
        ->min();
}
```

Comment: Is that so, can you please mark my answer as right answer?